# JSON Stringify Not Working on Array (ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, ajax

EDIT2: Found the solution, please see [JSON, AJAX, and ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036551/json-ajax-and-asp-net)

The problem ended up being that the parameter in the ajax call is NOT sent to the WebMethod on the server side as a string. The JSON string in the data field of the ajax call is actually converted to the object type specified in the WebMethod's parameter. That being said, my problem was that the data was not being passed into the WebMethod as a string, but a different object type.

EDIT: Looking at the browser console in Chrome, i'm getting this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error). Digging in deeper, I have the following response:

```
{"Message":"Type \u0027System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]\u0027 is not supported for deserialization of an array.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertListToObject(IList list, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, IList\u0026 convertedList)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object\u0026 convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

The following ajax call is never executed, and it seems like the data parameter does not have a valid value. If `data` is set equal to a string literal with valid JSON, there is no problem. There just seems to be an issue converting javascript objects into a valid parameter for `data` in the ajax call. Please see the below code snippet in my aspx file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready((function () {
            $('#mytable tr').click(function (event) {
                var array = [];
                $(".tdval").each(function () { 
                    array.push({
                        value: $(this).html()
                    });
                });
                alert(JSON.stringify(array)); //produces what appears to be valid json after calling stringify: [{"value":"val1"},{"value":"val2"}]

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "schedule.aspx/GetCurrentTime",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ array }), //this seems to be the issue
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response){
                        alert(response.d + "lol");
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        alert("complete");
                    }
                });
            });
        }));
    </script>
```

And this is the method in the C# code behind that the ajax call posts to:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
    {
        return "Hello ";
    }
```

Interestingly, I am able to change `data: JSON.stringify({ array })` in the ajax call to some random json as a string literal and it works fine as it should. But when using stringify, the "success" callback method from the ajax call is never executed. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why are there curly braces in the second stringify call? Dont think these are required..

Comment: `{ array }` is ES6 shorthand for `{ array: array }`. So the JSON will have the array in the `"array"` property of the JSON object. Is that what the controller expects?

Answer (score 0):

You have the array inside an object when you call `JSON.stringify()`, so the JSON you're sending will look like:

```
{ array: [{"value":"val1"},{"value":"val2"}] }
```

instead of what you alerted earlier in the function.

Instead, use:

```
data: JSON.stringify(array),
```

Comment: Still not working after removing the curly brackets. It was actually unintentional to use those, it was a remnant from troubleshooting. I used JSONLint to test whether the JSON is valid or not and it's saying it is. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked in the Network tab of the console to see if the AJAX request is being sent, what the parameters are, and what the response from the controller is?

Comment: When I use the string literal '{"name":"Bob"}' the code works. But using [{"value":"val1"},{"value":"val2"}] does not work despite JSONLint saying its valid JSON. I updated my code to show the C# codebehind method that this data is passed to as well so that all the code is available.

Comment: What Network tab? In browser or visual studio? I'm not familiar with monitoring what the parameters are outside of putting it in the debug console.

Comment: I'm talking about the browser console. Anyone working on browser applications should become familiar with the browser's developer tools console.

Comment: Indeed. I normally do back-end stuff in Java, im only familiar with ASP.NET and javascript basics... But anyways I'm going to look into getting the info being sent and post back here in a few mins.

Comment: it says:
 jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:61109/schedule.aspx/GetCurrentTime 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ schedule.aspx:33
dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3

Comment: and expanding the verbose option also includes "[Violation] 'load' handler took 3323ms" in the error description.

Comment: and expanding the verbose option also includes "[Violation] 'load' handler took 3323ms" in the error description.

Comment: When you see Internal Server Error, you need to check the log on the server to get the details. Something went wrong in the controller on the back-end.

Comment: Okay. I also posted my stack trace from the Network tab you were talking about. But ill go check whats going on in the server. The thing is, my C# webmethod in the code behind takes a string as a parameter. The only thing I can think of going wrong is that the parameter being passed into the method is NOT a string. Is stringify actually converting my js array into a string? If not, thats the problem.

Comment: Okay so I tried changing the type of parameter passed to the codebehind's Webmethod to Object. Still not working. I posted the stack trace in my OP, do you mind seeing if you can pose a suggestion?

Comment: Sorry, but asp.net is outside my wheelhouse, I'm probably not going to be able to help with debugging the back-end.